Consulta estructura HTML
Quise practicar el tema de eventos y html en Visual Studio Code, pero no resultó, quisiera que me dijeran en que fallé.

Por ejemplo quería que el texto de "Fechas de Racionamiento estuviera en una caja con fondo azul pero no me quedó así. Sino que me apareció una caja invisible debajo de la imagen que coloqué.
¿Por qué me ocurrió esto?

Y cree un botón que debía cambiar de azul a rojo, pero primero se creó un botón diminuto, y segundo es blanco, casi no se ve. ¿Porqué me ocurrió esto?

Por otro lado, lap página web no me lleva a ningún lado.

En el código le puse un texto a la imagen así: Alt=Juntos por el agua pero no me salió.

Todo lo descubrí porque cuando se abrió la página web, le di inspeccionar. Allí tambien me salio este signo ==$0 ¿Qué significa?
Ojalá me pudieran colaborar, hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo. Gracias.

Aquí describo el Código:
´´´´
`>``
     ><html>  

     ><head>  

     ><title>RACIONAMIENTO EN BOGOTÁ</title>  

     ></head>  

     ><body>  

     ><h1>Fechas de racionamiento</h1>  

     ><style>  

     >   #caja{  

     >   width: 500px;  

     >   height: 250px;  

     >   background-color: blue;  

     >   }  

     ></style>  

     ><a href>="https://shorturl.at/aNO04"</a>  

     ><img src="banner-juntos-por-el-Agua.jpg" alt="=juntos por el Agua"></img src>  

    ><div id="caja"></div>  

    ><button id="boton"></button>  

    ><script>  

    >var caja= document.getElementById("caja");  

    >var boton=document.getElementById("boton");  

    >boton.onclick=function(){  

    >caja.style.backgroundColor="red";  

    >};  

    ></script>  

    ></body>  

    ></html>  

´´´´



Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Pone tu htnl completo y como texto!! asi como imagen es imposible ayudarte...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
